# Blackboard with Struts

Tags: struts, blackboard

I am a beginner here, and this is my first time creating a building block for Blackboard. I understand that I could use Struts in building block thus I used Struts 1.3 to develop the building block for Blackboard version 9.

I am confuse while doing Dispatch Action, Blackboard doesn't seem to be able to find my forwarded page, and I keep ended up in this error "The specified resource was not found, or you do not have permission to access it".

Link in my jsp:

```
<a href="./teststruts.do">This is a test</a>
```

struts-config.xml setup:

```
<action path="/teststruts" type="com.test.action.TestAction" parameter="execute" scope="request" validate="false">
 <forward name="success" path="./thistest.jsp" />
 <forward name="error" path="./index.jsp" />
```

My dispatch action simply mapping.findforward to one of the path.

Really scratching my head here.

Comment: "The specified resource was not found, or you do not have permission to access it" - clearly says your struts mapping is correct. If the mapping was wrong, it would go to a 404 page. There is problem with problem with Blackboard permissions.

Answer (score 1):

Fix the relative path by removing the ./ from the front of your link.

Also verify that your Blackboard Building Block is starting up correctly by looking at the 
blackboard/logs/tomcat/sdtout-stderr log after you "disable and enable" the code from the Building Blocks management page.  Also verify that your servlet contains a error.jsp as sometimes the 404 error comes from struts forwarding the error on to an error page that does not exist.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
<permission name="suppressAccessChecks" type="java.lang.reflect.ReflectPermission"  />
```

But i don't think is a good idea to use struts or another framework to develop Blackboard BB. It can generate conflicts with the libraries used by Blackboard, if not with the current version, when updating Blackboard version.

One approach we took when trying to do complex modules in blackboard is to create a full webapp for Blackboard tomcat's instead of a BB. Using this technique it is possible to use whatever you want, since it is an independent application, but at the same time you can comunicate with Tomcat through the context. Yoy have to add the application to the server.xml and add some permissions in catalina.policy to do so... but maybe it could be a little bit tricky...